# Dynamic linq to sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, dynamic

using System.Linq.Dynamic
eg:

```
student.Where("studentno=@0","1001170101001")
```

SQL looks like:

```
exec sp_executesql N'select [Extent1].studentno,[Extent1].name.... from student
where [Extent1].[Name] =N''1001170101001''
```

but i want
SQL is:

```
exec sp_executesql N'select [Extent1].studentno,[Extent1].name.... from student
where [Extent1].[Name] =@DynamicFilterParam_000001',',N'@DynamicFilterParam_000001 nvarchar(50),
@DynamicFilterParam_000001='1001170101001'
```

eg2:

```
string studentno="1001170101001";
student.Where(q=>q.studentno == studentno);
```

this SQL is:

```
exec sp_executesql N'select [Extent1].studentno,[Extent1].name.... from student
where [Extent1].[Name] =@DynamicFilterParam_000001',',N'@DynamicFilterParam_000001 nvarchar(50),
@DynamicFilterParam_000001='1001170101001'
```

how do it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please tag which data base you are using, and ask a more specific question. So far your question is quite unclear.

Comment: Can you explain your expectation with more specific code?

Comment: What if you try  `student.AsQueryable().Where("studentno=@0","1001170101001")` ?

Comment: Why are you using Dynamic? A regular LINQ query will use parameters, depending on the LINQ provider you are using. Perhaps your database doesn't use parameters?

Comment: student is dbset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have already been solved!
Dynamic.cs
1.create dynamic class tempclass in ExpressionParser Constructor
Property from values
name like "@" + i.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
2.create instace object 4 tempclass and set property value
3.change Expression ParseIdentifier()
expr = Expression.Constant(value);
like this
expr = Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(tempclass), token.text);